# How to make phonegap app, 'don't use' full screen

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova

I'm creating a PhoneGap app in order to learn.

This is the code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>El Especialista</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="branca">
            <header>
                <img src="img/logo.png" /> 
            </header>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I update the phonegap app on my iPhone, the header starts on the top, under the notification bar (I mean, the notification bar is over my app, covering part of the application)

Check image at bottom to understand better.

How can I solve that? I mean, I know I can add a padding or margin to the top, so the app will start after the notification bar, but in Android or other devices the screen is different, and it wont work.

There is any kind of configuration, for making the app to be after the notification bar in iphone and android?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [cordova-plugin-statusbar](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config.xml you can put the preference fullscreen like this:

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

you can find some documentation here:

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/configuring_preferences.md.html